# Vanilla JS - How To Stop Sub-Element's OnClick Method From Calling Parent Elements OnClick Method

Tags: javascript, html

Having to use VanillaJS (don't ask me why).

Struggling to wrap my head around this simple thing.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function chooseImage() {
  alert("chooseImage");
}

function deleteImage() {
  alert("deleteImage");
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  background: black;
}
</style>

<div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <div class="mod-c-tab-img del-option" onclick="chooseImage()">
        <input type="radio" id="img-1" name="images" checked="">
        <label for="img-1"></label>
        <img src="https://public-assets.envato-static.com/assets/logos/envato_market-a5ace93f8482e885ae008eb481b9451d379599dfed24868e52b6b2d66f5cf633.svg" alt="">
        <button class="mod-del-btn" onclick="deleteImage()">>Delete</button>
    </div><!-- /.mod-c-tab-img -->
</div>
```

And view it on a codepen here: https://codepen.io/jacksonjack/pen/MWKgQQK

Now two things should happen:

1. user should click image and it should popup with an alert "chooseImage".

This works as expected.

However the second thing does not work as expected.

2. user should click image and it should popup with an alert "deleteImage".

However it shows "deleteImage" then the "chooseImage".

How do I stop this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation Yet the correct solution here would be to remove the `click` event on the `div`and assign it to the actual image `img`.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to event bubbling.  Use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the global event object from bubbling at that moment.  I would also recommend using js to add your event listener so you can grab the event object as an argument rather than having to access it globally.

```js
function chooseImage() {
  alert("chooseImage");
}

function deleteImage() {
  event.stopPropagation()
  alert("deleteImage");
}
```

Comment: `I would also recommend using js to add your event listener so you can grab the event object as an argument rather than having to access it globally.` Would you mind to elaborate on this one? Neither requires any access to a global event object. Unless you are  stuck in <IE6..

Comment: Sure ! @JavaScript since there is not an event parameter setup the function is accessing the event object in its lexical scope, which is the global scope, if you were to use the addEventListener method, the browser would inject a parameter object as the first parameter to the callback function.

Comment: Firstly, the event parameter gets provided in both cases. Secondly, it is not required if done properly.

Comment: @JavaScript If you feel there is a more appropriate way to solve the problem, feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like I already wrote in my comment, you may use [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the bubbling of events.

However, in this case it would suffice to just put the `click` event from the `div` to the `img`, which brings both events to separate siblings.

```js
function chooseImage() {
  alert("chooseImage");
}

function deleteImage() {
  alert("deleteImage");
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <div class="mod-c-tab-img del-option">
        <input type="radio" id="img-1" name="images" checked="">
        <label for="img-1"></label>
        <img src="https://public-assets.envato-static.com/assets/logos/envato_market-a5ace93f8482e885ae008eb481b9451d379599dfed24868e52b6b2d66f5cf633.svg" alt="" onclick="chooseImage()">
        <button class="mod-del-btn" onclick="deleteImage()">>Delete</button>
    </div><!-- /.mod-c-tab-img -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function chooseImage() {
  alert("chooseImage");
}

function deleteImage(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("deleteImage");
}
```

```html
<div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <div class="mod-c-tab-img del-option" onclick="chooseImage()">
        <input type="radio" id="img-1" name="images" checked="">
        <label for="img-1"></label>
        <img src="https://public-assets.envato-static.com/assets/logos/envato_market-a5ace93f8482e885ae008eb481b9451d379599dfed24868e52b6b2d66f5cf633.svg" alt="">
        <button class="mod-del-btn" onclick="deleteImage(event)">Delete</button>
    </div><!-- /.mod-c-tab-img -->
</div>
```

Firstly you need to call delete image with `event`. Then only `stopPropagation` would work.

```
<button class="mod-del-btn" onclick="deleteImage(event)">Delete</button>

function deleteImage(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("deleteImage");
}
```